# Google Analytics not showing visitors - Magento ver. 2.3.5-p2

Tags: google-analytics, magento2.3.5-p2

For some reason google analytics is not showing any visitors.
I have added the google Account Number on backend.
Analytics code also shows on the frontend but no data is being populated on google analytics.

Can anyone help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share detailed desciption with provided snapshots if possible.

Comment: Have edited the question and added images. The tracking code shows in source code but there is no tracking on google analytics.